# How to change the background color of secondary toolbar - xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, toolbar, navigationbar

[image]Using `Navigation` renderer I tried changing the background color of toolbar by setting the following.

```
this.Toolbar.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
```

But my secondary toolbar color is not getting changed.

Can anyone let me know how to change the background color of secondary tool bar in xamarin iOS ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_nav_bar_color/

Comment: I'm talking about the secondary toolbar...The one that you enable with the Order attribute: <ToolbarItem Icon="icon1.png"></ToolbarItem> <ToolbarItem Icon="icon2.png"></ToolbarItem> <ToolbarItem Icon="icon3.png" Order="Secondary" Text="Task3"></ToolbarItem> <ToolbarItem Icon="icon4.png" Order="Secondary" Text="Task4"></ToolbarItem>

Comment: what is `Toolbar`, do you mean the toolbar in custom renderer `NavigationRenderer` , and also could you attach the image to describe your issue, I think it will be more intuitive

Comment: @ColeXia While adding toolbar items if the order is specified to be secondary..the items are added in a secondary tool bar below the navigationbar .. Thanks ..I have added the image also for reference.

Comment: have you ever found an answer for this? please let me know if you did

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following way:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(ExtendedNavigationRenderer))]
namespace Sample.iOS
{
    public class ExtendedNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        UIToolbar _secondaryToolbar;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //_secondaryToolbar = View.Subviews.OfType<UIToolbar>().FirstOrDefault(v => v.GetType() != typeof(UIToolbar));
            _secondaryToolbar = View.Subviews.OfType<UIToolbar>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (_secondaryToolbar != null)
                _secondaryToolbar.BarTintColor = this.NavigationBar.BarTintColor;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            if (_secondaryToolbar != null && _secondaryToolbar.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (UIBarButtonItem item in _secondaryToolbar.Items)
                {
                    var label = item.CustomView.Subviews.OfType<UILabel>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (label != null)
                    {
                        label.TextColor = UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes.ForegroundColor;
                        //label.Font = label.Font.WithSize(12f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

(TintColor approach brings the real color that is slightly different from primary NavigationBar, but NavigationBar.BackgroundColor is null)